# Can't reach localhost:PORT created in Node.js and express

Tags: node.js, express

```
    require('dotenv').config();

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors);

const connectDB = require('./config/mongoDB');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;

// body parser
app.use(express.json({ extended: false }));

//router
app.use(
  '/',
  require('./routes/index')
);

app.listen(PORT, (req, res) => {
  connectDB();
  console.log('listening on port ' + PORT);
});
```

so this is my express server code, it was working yesterday but I can't reach localhost: PORT (via postman and browser) today but it is running and listening to PORT. Where it goes wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The `cors` middleware should be called with parenthesis, as a function:

```
app.use(cors());
```

2. You are setting the body parser middleware incorrectly, change

```
app.use(express.json({ extended: false }));
```

to:

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Comment: thank you for the help, took me so.. long to realize this. Really appreciate the help.